# reset workspace env

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I accidentally clicked Go: reset workspace env in Visual Studio Code, and the local Go environment won't work

My Go version is 1.18

> Failed to run '/usr/local/go/bin/go env' (cwd: /Users/kejie/go/ms): Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go env -json GOPATH GOROOT GOPROXY GOBIN GOMODCACHE
> the path provided to GOWORK must be an absolute path
>
> the path provided to GOWORK must be an absolute path

```
➜  go env
```

> the path provided to GOWORK must be an absolute path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What does `echo $GOWORK` say? Reset it if not empty from the commandline e.g. `unset GOWORK`, and relaunch vscode with the new env var.
- If user profile or workspace settings.json has `go.toolsEnvVars` field, try to delete the field and restart vscode.